# Console.ReadLine() showing "Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type."

Tags: c#, string, input, nullable-reference-types

New to C#. I am trying this code, which I copied from w3school User Input

```cs
using System;
 
namespace Sample
{
    class Test
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string testString;
            Console.Write("Enter a string - ");
            testString = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You entered '{0}'", testString);
        }
    }
}
```

But after I execute the Program, it shows an error at `Console.ReadLine()`;

**Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.**

Comment: It's possible for `Console.ReadLine()` to return `null`, which it does if there's no data. Therefore you cannot assign the result to a `string` which is not allowed to be `null`. Instead you have to declare `testString` as a nullable string by appending `?` like this: `string? testString;`

Comment: The use of `?` to indicate a nullable reference type was probably introduces after the code you're using was written, so it's a little out-of-date.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of .NET, nullable reference types are supported by default and Console.ReadLine returns a nullable string. That means that you need to either declare your variable as nullable:

```
string? testString;
```

or specify that the return value will definitely not be null:

```
testString = Console.ReadLine()!;
```

If you use the former, you'll have allow for that when you use the variable later. The latter is OK because, in a console window, it will never be null.

You ought to do some reading on nullable reference types.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you have a valid non-null `string`.

You could do this for example to make sure that it's valid before printing it to the console using the formatter:

```cs
testString = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
```

This will assign an empty `string` to the `testString` variable in case that `ReadLine()` returns `null`.